# Loop to check a variable

Tags: java, loops

I want to loop through an array, then I want to do a check to see if the element in the arrayList is bigger than a certain number.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NewUser.getList().size(); i++){
     if(UserAge < 50){
         System.print.out.ln(UserAge)
      }

 }
```

but Im not sure on this, because i don't know how to use every element of the arrayList as part of the if, not UserAge

Comment: The question isn't clear.

Comment: Well in your current code you're not using `i` at all in the loop... or indeed `NewUser`. It's unclear what all the variables are here. It's also very odd that you've got a *variable* called `getList` when that would normally be the name of a method. Can you give us more context?

Comment: I have an arrayList of numbers, which for context are the ages of people. I want to loop through this arrayList and print all the ages of the people that are younger than 50. getList() is an accessor method to get the arrayList as it is in anoter class

Answer (score 1):

If it's an `ArrayList` you can simply iterate it without using counts etc:

```
for( int i : myList ){
  if( i > 50 ){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it bluntly, you're not retrieving the elements from your list.  You're comparing against a static value which will never change throughout the loop.

(You've also got some fun syntax issues, but I'll overlook those for now...)

To retrieve the elements, you have two options:

- Use the `i` variable:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < NewUser.getList().size(); i++){
      Integer userAge = NewUser.getList().get(i);
      if(userAge < 50){
          System.out.println(userAge);
      }
  }
  ```
- Use the [enhanced-for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), giving you a variable for free:

  ```
  for(Integer userAge : NewUser.getList()){
      if(userAge < 50){
          System.out.println(userAge);
      }
  }
  ```

Enhanced for is recommended for collections, as it reads a lot clearer.  Only index into collections and arrays if you need to get something at an *exact* position.